# Python - cloning a list

Tags: python

I want to make clones of every tuple in list1, so that the list in the tuple `[1, 0, 1]` is cloned with exactly one number differing from the original tuple, such that it adds to the newlist to make it:

```
[([0, 0, 1], 'a'), ([0, 1, 1], 'a'), ([1, 0, 0], 'a')]
```

However, what it is returning me is

```
[[[0, 1, 0], 'a'], [[0, 1, 0], 'a'], [[0, 1, 0], 'a']].
```

```
list1 = [([1, 0, 1], 'a')]
list2 = list1.copy()
newlist = []
for x in list2:
    for i in range(len(x[0])):
        new_x = list(x).copy()
        if x[0][i] == 1:
            new_x[0][i] -= 1
            newlist.append(new_x)
        elif x[0][i] == 0:
            new_x[0][i] += 1
            newlist.append(new_x)
print(newlist)
```

Comment: you want ([0, 1, 1], 'a') in the answer? But how is it different from original input in exactly one number? At least in two numbers as far as I can tell

Comment: @NikolayZakirov yesss sorry was a typo! thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should shallow-copy `x[0]`. If not, the all inner-lists are same list, so they will share their elements.

I refactored two points:

- use tuple unpacking in for-loop. `for bits, character in ...`
- use bit inversion with boolean operator. `int(not new_bits[i])` <- I assumed that the inner-lists only include 0 or 1.

```py
original_list = [([1, 0, 1], 'a')]
new_list = []
for bits, character in original_list:
    for i in range(len(bits)):
        new_bits = bits.copy()
        new_bits[i] = int(not new_bits[i])
        new_list.append((new_bits, character))
print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[([0, 0, 1], 'a'), ([1, 1, 1], 'a'), ([1, 0, 0], 'a')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert them back to the tuples

```
list1 = [([1, 0, 1], 'a')]
list2 = list1.copy()
newlist = []
for x in list2:
    for i in range(len(x[0])):
        new_x = list(x).copy() # <- converting to the list
        if x[0][i] == 1:
            new_x[0][i] -= 1
            newlist.append(tuple(new_x)) # <- converting to the tuple
        elif x[0][i] == 0:
            new_x[0][i] += 1
            newlist.append(tuple(new_x)) # <- converting to the tuple
print(newlist)
```

Comment: You don't need to call `list.copy` just after creating a new list.

Comment: @Boseong Choi good point

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I think you should copy `x[0]` for OP's expectation.

Comment: @arphsd You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [([1, 0, 1], 'a')]

newlist = []
for sublist in list1:
    for i in range(len(sublist[0])):
        new_item = sublist[0].copy()
        new_item[i] += 1
        new_item[i] %= 2
        newlist.append((new_item, sublist[1]))
print(newlist)
```

returns

```
[([0, 0, 1], 'a'), ([1, 1, 1], 'a'), ([1, 0, 0], 'a')]
```